# Need some help positioning a header and sub heading

Tags: html, css

heres my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEqJLr#anon-login
heres what I'm trying to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqD2G.jpg
basically I want the sub header ("helpthistext") to be above my header and I'm not sure how to achieve this..

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

.newtest {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="newtest">
  <span class="sub-head">helpthistext</span>
  <h1 class="main-head">title one & another one</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flex-direction:column` is what you are after

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: red;
text-align:Center;
}

.newtest {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="newtest">
  <span class="sub-head">helpthistext</span>
  <h1 class="main-head">title one & another one</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this does position it above the header. How would I move it to the left, so that it's like this: https://imgur.com/a/NxvyHAC

Comment: You'd have to center `.newtest` and make it only as wide as it needs to be - answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the flex direction to the newtest.

```
.newtest {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 75%;
      flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes sense to have the `.sub-head` appear beneath the `.main-head` in the markup, even if you want to visually display it above the main heading in the browser viewport.

To achieve this, apply `display: flex` to `.newtest` and then:

- give `.main-head` an order of `2`
- give `.sub-head` an order of `1`

  **Working Example:**

```css
.newtest {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main-head {
order: 2;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 0;
}

.sub-head {
width: 100%;
order: 1;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newtest">    
<h1 class="main-head">title one &amp; another one</h1>
<div class="sub-head">helpthistext</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code...

```
<div class="myDiv">
  <h3>helpthistext</h3>
  <h1>title one & another one</h1>
</div>
```

```
.myDiv {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.myDiv h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.myDiv h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```